# What com.apple.quarantine value should I set to mark a file as potentially malicious?

Tags: macos, osx-gatekeeper, xattr

I'm making a [desktop application](https://github.com/iffy/lhtml/issues/75) which will open files (of the LHTML format) and which can save files (of whatever format) to a user's computer.  In other words, a user might:

1. Download `something.lhtml` from an email they receive
2. Open `something.lhtml`
3. Be prompted to save `stuff.ppt` by this application (where the contents of `stuff.ppt` are determined by `something.lhtml`)
4. Double click `stuff.ppt`

When the user opens `stuff.ppt`, I want them to be prompted before opening the file **as if they had downloaded `stuff.ppt` from an email.**  So... if I copy `something.lhtml`'s **current** `com.apple.quarantine` extended attribute to `stuff.ppt`, is that guaranteed to force a prompt when `stuff.ppt` is opened?

And if the file being saved isn't a `.ppt` but is one of these, is copying the `com.apple.quarantine` value still sufficient?

- `.exe`
- `.pdf`
- `.dmg`
- `.app`

Does this question even make sense? :)